# Trying to use XML::Parser and XML::XPath, where do I type the command?

Tags: windows-xp, mysql, xml, perl, parsing

Here's the tutorial I am using, which I have been assured is of high quality by Google: http://www.kitebird.com/articles/mysql-xml.html#TOC_5

Now, what I am trying to do is run some test scripts against some XML files, porting the data into my MySQL database tables.

Where do I type in the commands?  Can I run PHP and type them in there?  Do I have to install a program?  Because Google doesn't recognize `::` as being part of a word, so I wouldn't know where to download.  Would the script run from a browser if the filename had the right extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Parser-2.36/Parser.pm) and [XML::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-XPath-1.13/XPath.pm) are perl libraries

First you need to install perl.
Go to http://strawberryperl.com/ and install the latest version.

Then to install the libraries open a command prompt and type

```
C:\>cpan XML:Parser
```

That will start the installation. You will probably see a lot of text and get a few questions. You can probably choose the default answer every time (if in doubt answer yes)

Then do the same for

```
 C:\>cpan XML:Path
```

To run a perl script invoke perl with the name of the script

```
C:\>perl name_of_script_you_want_to_run.pl
```

And to answer your other questions:

- No PHP can't run it
- No your browser can't run it
- To google for XML::XPath works just fine in FF, IE and chrome, but in the future try putting your string between "" if it contains funny chars.

---

### IMPORTANT

#### IF YOU HAVE ANY PROBLEMS INSTALLING PERL; INSTALLING THE LIBRARIES; RUNNING THE SCRIPT FROM THE TUTORIAL

#### ASK NEW QUESTIONS!

Follow up questions in the comments will be ignored if they deal with these things